# regional settings does it update spellcheck

Tags: regional-settings

I am wondering if changing the regional settings will update the spellchecker or will I have to write the powershell again to include a localeID thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not update the spell Checker, you have to manually change it.

> regardless of what language you have set your locale or settings to in your SharePoint instance that the spellchecker dictionary ALWAYS defaults to US English

read this blog for more details:

http://clintoncherry.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/changing-the-langauge-of-the-sharepoint-spell-checker/